# Is possible to pass parameter in ajax request with dynamic parameter name in asp,net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have doubt on ajax request. I send a ajax request post in asp.net. I have passed parameter in ajax request. If i changed the parameter name in code behind (aspx.cs), then the request was not post. I checked with mvc, its working for any parameter name. Is it default behavior in asp.net? or i missed anything?

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   data:{value:JSON.stringify(data)},
   url:default.aspx/GetData
 )};
```

**CS**

```
  [WebMethod]
  public static void GetData(Student value)
  {
     //code here
  }
```

In the abouve cs file, if i give the parameter name as "value" then the post was successfully done, if i changed the parameter name to anything, the post get failure. Kindly advise me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In System.Web.Routing.RouteParser, explicit string comparisons are performed to validate the route that you intend to take. As a result, if your parameter name is different from what has been stored in the RouteTable, MVC Routing is unable to discover the route.  They would have to make a change (and most likely a dangerous and unsecure one at that) to allow wildcard parameter names.

```
public BoundUrl Bind(RouteValueDictionary currentValues, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteValueDictionary defaultValues, RouteValueDictionary constraints)
{
    ...
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValuePair in values)
    {
        if (ParsedRoute.IsRoutePartNonEmpty(keyValuePair.Value) && !acceptedValues.ContainsKey(keyValuePair.Key))
      acceptedValues.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
    }
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValuePair in currentValues)
    {
        string key = keyValuePair.Key;
        if (!acceptedValues.ContainsKey(key) && ParsedRoute.GetParameterSubsegment(this.PathSegments, key) == null)
      acceptedValues.Add(key, keyValuePair.Value);
    }
    ...
}
```

Since the routing Bind method is looking specifically at the string key values, they need to match what you originally registered.

Answer (score 2):

yes , it won't work if you change the parameter name on the server side . The client-side parameter name and the server side one should be same else the server won't recognize it as the send parameter .

I don't know why it is but it works this way only .

Thanks !